# Java primitive variables types

Tags: variables, type-conversion, primitive

Why does Java need to have byte, short primitive variables types even though they are automatically promoted to int type? Why not declare int type at the outset?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you will only use boolean, int, and double.  Sometimes char and long will be used also.  The official Java API says that the other types byte, short, and float are almost strictly for saving memory for when a huge number of variables is needed, as in thousands to millions.  Which is something that most beginning programmers don't need to worry about.

If memory is a problem, which isn't likely on today's computers, and the values you need will fit into a byte (such as age since no one has lived into the 120's yet), then you could have four byte primitives in the space of one int primitive.  In the early days of programming, this was a huge savings.  Since memory is in groups of 8 even for boolean, by using bitwise operators, an 8 bit variable could actually hold 8 boolean values when it would normally take 64 bits as 8 boolean variables.  A savings of 8:1.

The reason that the other types are automatically promoted to int is because simple binary operations, especially multiplication, can easily give a result out of the range of the smaller primitives.

```
// This simple operation gives a result that cannot be stored in a byte
byte b = 10 * 13;
```

Of course, once the calculation is made, a cast is needed and in this case it will even give a negative number, -126.  That could be a problem if it is computing something that needs to be positive, like area.

Answer (score 0):

They are not automatically promoted. They are promoted through implicit casting.